# Proof a piecewise function is darboux integrable on $[-1,3]$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Given $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
-2 &-1\leq x\lt 0\\
1 & x=0 \\
2 & 0 \lt x \leq 3
\end{cases}
$$
I need to prove $g$ is Darboux integrable on $[-1,3]$. When I read Bartle's book, I feel like that I need to define partition and my idea is $\mathcal{P}=(-1,-\epsilon,\epsilon,3)$ for $\epsilon \gt0$ then try to find the lower sum and upper sum from the partition. When I tried to compute, I found this

$$L(f;\mathcal{P})=-2(-\epsilon-(-1))-2(\epsilon - (-\epsilon)+2(3-\epsilon) = 4 - 4\epsilon \\
U(f;\mathcal{P})=-2(-\epsilon-(-1))+2(\epsilon - (-\epsilon)+2(3-\epsilon)=4+4\epsilon$$

Is this approach correct? If not, what is the correct approach?
If this approach is correct :

1. Even though I came up with such partition, I still confused. Is such partition correct? Should we include $x=0$ inside the partition? Generally, how do we come up with such partition?
2. After finding the lower sum and upper sum, what I saw in Bartle's book is saying that $U(f) \leq something$, and $L(f) \geq something$. How do we conclude this?

I'm sorry if I asked too many questions. It's okay if you can't answer all of it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know riemann's condition

Comment: Yes, where we need to check for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ the $|S(f;\mathcal{P})-L|\lt \epsilon$, isn't it?

Comment: No, where you know integrable iff $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists \ P \ U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \varepsilon$

Comment: Oh yes, I know that.

Comment: Then you have solved the problem you see